# Apache failing to start

Tags: server, apache2, 16.04

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04, I decided to reinstall Apache after phpMyAdmin was throwing a HTTP 500 error.

Since reinstalling it, on an attempt to start the Apache service I receive this error.

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
```

Running the commands specified in the error message gives the following response:

```
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apac
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]:  *
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]: Output of config test was:
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /et
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]: Action 'configtest' failed.
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 apache2[8270]: The Apache error log may have more infor
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, co
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 07:35:36 vps71254 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-c
May 20 07:35:38 vps71254 sudo[7695]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for
```

I have tried installing and uninstalling the whole apache package several times but the same error is thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you also post apache logs ?

Comment: Use `systemctl -l status apache2` to retrieve the logs in a not-trimmed format.  It will show us full-length reports and give you specifics about the EXACT syntax error you're running into.

Answer (score 2):

What was your **syntax on line 140 of your apache2.conf** file? It's telling you where the problem is.

I have an identical readout to yours but mine was on a different line, which calls to include phpmyadmin's config file.

I #'d the line out (`nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`) and was able to `service apache2 restart`.

Then I installed phpmyadmin `apt install phpmyadmin`, uncommented that troubling line (again `nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` can be easier for counting lines), and restarted again with `service apache2 restart` flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the installations for installing apache

Remove apache first: sudo apt-get remove apache2

sudo apt-get install apache2

then:

sudo apachectl start

(in your browser, type in "localhost")

If it doesn't work try restarting apache (sudo apachectl restart)

When you're done i'll give you the installations for phpmyadmin, if you already have php.

Hope this helps.